# Can a top plate on a 2x6 exterior walled be drilled for wires in 2 adjacent bays?

Tags: framing, subpanel, structural, nec

I am installing a 125A sub panel next to an existing main panel/ The sub panel will be in the stud bay next to the main. Both of these are on a 2x6 exterior load bearing wall. I understand the hole setback limitations and the need for a 16g strap on the top plate but It seems I saw a thread or comment somewhere that you could not drill the top plate in two consecutive stud bays. I can't find this anywhere in code. Am I missing it? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: How big are the holes you are drilling in the top plate? If you are boring a centered hole more than 1/2 the width of the 2x6 then you need the strap - that's a big ele cable !!

Comment: I am dropping 18 12/2's and 1 6/3 so there will be 6 1-1/2" holes.  My question is can the top plate be drilled in two consecutive bays on a load bearing wall.  I know there will need to be strapping in any case.  thanks